# Careers feature request: Dream Jobs

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

I think a great user-input for Careers would be "Dream Jobs."

I personally believe companies should be eager to hire an engineer that is passionate about the technologies they utilize. -- Many engineers (like me) fall into "career traps" that they would desperately like to escape.

Depending on the circumstances, I might eagerly consider a job ***for practically no salary*** if it involved a technology that I was interested in studying. (e.g. Python-based web apps?)

**Update:**

I'm afraid my blurb about working for no pay has skewed my intent.

What I was trying to suggest was it would be nice to have a section for "Technologies I'm Interested in Working With." -- I'm personally fortunate in that I have demonstrated success in a niche skill-set (as reflected in my resume) but would really enjoy learning something new. I'm certainly a believer in self-motivated study (in the very few hours I have away from my current day job) but making the switch without a defined project/projects to work on can only take you so far.

Comment: So if my job just happens to include some of these "interesting technologies to learn", I would gladly pay you $10/day to do my job for me. I'll enjoy the salary and you enjoy the work. Everyone wins! haha.

Comment: Hm.. On the face of it, "working for ~free" may sound rather silly.. but, this is basically how you get into the "film industry": 1) work for free in an area you're interested in, 2) do a good job, 3) get paid work on the directors future work. Not quite sure the same applies to programming - seems this is the void filled by working on open-source projects..

Comment: I thought the way to get into the film industry was to sleep with the producer? That really isn't going to work in the software industry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the '`Favorite Technologies`' tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe how such a feature might manifest itself in the site? e.g. a description of your ideal job (technologies, working conditions, hours etc)?

Comment: I've updated the original post.  What I was hoping for was something akin to "technologies I'm interested in working with."