# Statistics on what employers are actually searching for

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

Just thinking down the road to when Careers is accepting employer signups, I think it'd be a really great promotion and informational view to be able to see what types of tags and searches companies are doing.

For example, I think it'd be valuable during the signup process for prospective job-seekers to see:

- 65% of employers are searching for `C#`
- 22% of employers are searching for `Java and Spring`
- etc.

I think having some level of visibility into what employers are actually searching for (at an aggregate level) might help the job-seekers know what exactly it is that employers are currently looking for, and how they can better market themselves to those interests - although I suppose the argument could be made that the type of developer that SO Careers is targeting shouldn't need to do that sort of thing.

I just think it'd be great for paid users to be able to see some level of details as to how employers are using the system, so they can tell if they are getting any value for their registration cost.

Comment: I am sure if you have the attitude of Nate over here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27200/careers-feature-request-dream-jobs you will have no trouble finding work. ;)

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30763/hits-vs-searches-statistics-on-stack-overflow-careers

Comment: Duplicate? This question is 21 days older than yours

Comment: That's amazing. @George Stocker asks the same question, then tries to get the older one claimed as a dupe. The balls of this guy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** This feature was removed in Careers 2.0

<s>We now have **public employer search statistics** for CV holders, under the stats tab -- just click "show detail>>" to expand.</s>

This list is queried dynamically about every hour, and reflects current live data.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

More important and less controversial than tags is location. Show what are the most solicited locations and see which searches are location limited, and to which locations.

I really want to know if my CV sucks, or if most searches are restricted by location.

Comment: 100% agree.  I just came onto meta to ask this question and make this point.

Comment: Yeah emphasis on "I really want to know if my CV sucks", with a side of "not sure if I am using the tags appropriately".

Answer (score 4):

I agree that visibility into some sort of volume number would help, but being too specific will lead to users gaming the system.

Comment: Absolutely I agree - there's some level of detail tradeoff involved

Comment: Everybody is gaming everything. There's plenty of stats already out there so I don't see the problem with revealing them here... it would just help people like me reconcile what they want to do against demand.

Answer (score 2):

Must be broken, Michigan shows up on there:

[image]

Comment: I'm more surprised with Romania, Serbia and Norway being there.

Comment: I upvoted, just to see you rush to make it CW ;)

Comment: @yoda Must... resist... temptation...!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to second this, but I'd really like to see more than just aggregate level stats, if possible. I know it'd be a bear to build reports on it, but I'd like to see exactly what each employer *is* searching for. Keywords, tags, locations... everything.

Answer (score 1):

If employers are looking for certain aspects that I can do in an area that I might consider, I would like to know that and adjust my CV accordingly. What I really want to know is if they're just not looking for someone like me, or someone close to someone like me. I don't think it's gaming the system to do this - as the goal is to match an suitably awesome employer with a suitably awesome employee. The employer (usually) knows what they want - we need to be able to put ourselves in their line of sight.