# Information about what searches are being done on Careers

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs, search

So, I can see how many searches are performed on Careers. And I can see how few times my CV has been part of the result set. This is a bit depressing!

What I'd love is some more information about the kinds of searches being done. Kind of like Google's [Hot Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends) pages. Or even StackOverflow's own [Tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) pages. Just knowing what tags are turning up in searches or results would be very helpful in tuning the CV. If everyone's searching for `java` I'm not going to throw it in there just because (I'm not a Java guy), but if `sql` is getting hits left and right then I'd want to make sure I have that tagged somewhere (since I do speak fluent database).

For that matter, it would be interesting to see this sort of information aggregated from CVs as well.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28475/statistics-on-what-employers-are-actually-searching-for

Answer (score 7):

It would be nice to have - I'm a statistics junkie.

However, there is a chance that the results will be poisoned if people know more about what employers are looking for, and the site *may* become less useful if even a few dozen people decide to 'follow the trends' with their resume.

Not only is it a double edged sword, but the purpose of the site is to advertise good people and have the employers search.  This is the reverse of most other job sites, and a key feature.  The more we know about the jobs and employers, the more we turn the site into one of the existing job search sites.

Be patient.  There's only 12 beta employers on there.  The purpose of the website isn't to get everyone a job, the purpose is to connect really great developers with really great employers.  The site is working if you show up in only a few searches - the laser focus means that when you do show up, it will be a much better match for you and the employer than on most other sites where you might show up in dozens of worse matches.

Answer (score 6):

Knowing what employers are searching for could mean that some people would tailor their CVs to come up in searches (by, for example, adding in technologies that a potential employer is searching for even though they might not have (much) experience in it), thus playing the system.

It would however be useful to know about the locations used in searches, as that is pretty hard to fabricate - you either will work there or you won't.

Answer (score 4):

Information about the locations that are being searched for would be useful too - especially for people who are willing to relocate.

Comment: And don't forget about people outside the US.

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice if users could search the site, to check that search terms are matching their CV.

If I have no hits on my CV I want to know if that's because Jeff's coding can't match "c/c++" or it's just because nobody hires real programmers anymore.

- you could strip the name/contact info if you think recruiters would use this as a cheap backdoor

Answer (score 1):

Statistics on the tags, particularly, would be helpful. Since tags are limitless it would be nice to know if a particular tag gets any hits or if it's a total waste of space. I might find that people are searching for some other similar tag that I wouldn't have thought to use instead.

On the other hand, I wouldn't be surprised if the search breakdown was somewhat similar to the top tags on SO. The most popular technologies are almost always going to be the ones in demand.

The "poison the system argument" can also be seen in reverse: if I could see the popularity of the tags and find out that there are 1000 other people using the same tags I am, I might want to change my tags to use *less* common terms so that I separate from the crowd.