# Hits vs Searches statistics on Stack Overflow careers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, jobs, statistics

This question has two parts, one feature request, and one discussion related item.

#### Feature Request

Can we have a statistic available that tells us how often we show up in searches compared to other candidates?  Specifically, I know that I show up in about 10% of the searches done by Employers; but I want to compare that percentage against other candidates.

The reasoning is if I have a lower percentage, then I know that I'm 'doing it wrong', and I have hard numbers to prove that.

It would also help to know how often employers are searching certain items (say the 'trending' programming language; which language is on the rise, etc). I realize TIOBE [carries an index](http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) on language popularity; but it isn't really 'local' enough to be useful.

#### Discussion

What other statistics would you like to see for Careers? What metrics would be helpful to you in measuring the effectiveness of your CV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first half of your request is very unlikely to happen.

Be aware that you joined early and have a very low ID number; in some cases when there is no sort order, we use ID by default, which means you'll show up artificially high in the absence of other sort orders. This is OK and partially intentional as we thought it was smart to reward early adopters.

The second half of your request is complete, so I am marking this [status-complete].

[Information about what searches are being done on Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/information-about-what-searches-are-being-done-on-careers)

That's the downside of having two requests in the same question..

Comment: Given that you've marked up my top rated questions as `[Status-declined]` I'll take a partial [Status-Complete] over none any day. :-D

Answer (score 4):

I agree on the "how often are employers searching certain items".

It would also be great to see regional statistics. I personally show up in less than 1% of the searches. I guess that my coming from Switzerland is the reason, but I do not know.

I also would like to use careers as an employer. I would use the regional statistics as well to decide on whether to join or not. Only critical masses of people in the EU and Switzerland searching would make me join.

It would also be great to know what search criteria are available in the first place - is it possible to do a world wide search, and how often is this done?

How about a stats page that does not need a login, showing distributions on region, favorites, and likes (combinations, maybe including dislikes)?

Comment: this is completed; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/information-about-what-searches-are-being-done-on-careers