# Show some indicator of job post activity

Tags: discussion, jobs

There are plenty of jobs posted on Careers.  I think it would be helpful for job searchers to know about a few statistics of the jobs we are looking at applying to.

Information of interest to applicants might be things that indicate the competition for a particular posting. May be things like:

- Number of views on the posting
- Number of "favorites" for the posting

Also, a couple of other questions requested statistical information about job searches -- previously available, but now since removed.

- [Statistics on what employers are actually searching for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28475/statistics-on-what-employers-are-actually-searching-for)
- [Information about what searches are being done on Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/information-about-what-searches-are-being-done-on-careers/34887#comment652942_34887) [dupe of above]

Careers is great for getting information about yourself out there, but in terms of closing the feedback loop / telling you how "well" you're doing, or how interesting your profile looks to others, there isn't much info (besides Search Hits and Employer Views).

My question is for Careers site designers.  Why isn't more information available to job hunters?  Can you expose more information?

Answer (score 3):

Specific to the stats you have listed, number of views on the posting and number of favorites, they are pretty useless stats.  Your decision to apply for a job or not should be dependent on the job description itself, not some artificial stats about how many other people are interested in it.

That being said, we think there are some useful statistics to show candidates that can help job seekers make decisions more effectively.  All of these things are related to the collection of all jobs however, not the collection of other candidates.  Think you'd like to try living on the west coast for a change?  Maybe a breakdown of the number of jobs hiring for specific technologies in the major cities over the last 6 months will help you narrow down exactly where you'd like to go or help you figure out which skills you should brush up on to make yourself more valuable in a specific location.